# How to set the timeout using an input build parameter? I am using declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

```
 parameters {

         string(defaultValue: "3.0", description: '', name: 'duration')
     }

     options {
         timeout(time: params.duration, unit: 'HOURS')
     }
```

This does not work as because params.duration contains is an empty string. So how do I set the timeout using an input build parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    parameters {
        string(defaultValue: "3", description: '', name: 'duration')
    }

    options {
        timeout(time: params.duration as int, unit: 'HOURS')
    }
```

Output:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on jenkins-host in /home/try2
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] timeout
Timeout set to expire in 3 hr 0 min
```

Comment: Hi..Thanks for the answer but I get this error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
 at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)`  I think params.duration is still an empty string and therefore I get this exception when I try to convert it to int

Comment: Your first run may fail, but the second one should recognize the parameters. If you see "Build with Parameters" in your job instead of "Build", this says Jenkins will suggest you input the desired duration.

Comment: Oh, about the error on the first run. I was able to prevent that adding a condition to get the `params.duration`, doing something like `params.duration == null ? 20 : params.durations`